# The functional relationship between LDR and output voltage in a light activated differential amplifier

Tags: amplifier, function

while learning about amplifiers, I found that this circuit cannot be quantitatively analyzed and I need help.

I have two questions:

1. LDR as a function of the input and output voltage of the amplifier (indicated by the arrow in the figure)
2. The role of VR2 in circuits

[image: schematic]

Image adapted from: [Electronics Tutorials - Light Activated Differential Amplifier](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/opamp/opamp_5.html)

Comment: The LDR datasheet will tell you how its resistance varies according to the level of illumination it receives. That should be enough to allow you to analyse how the circuit will behave.

Comment: Also, the circuit doesn't have a linear relationship between R and Vout, it implements a [Schmitt Trigger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schmitt_trigger)

Comment: Iceeman - Hi, Please remember the [site rule](/help/referencing) which requires that when a post includes content (e.g. text, image, photo etc.) copied or adapted from elsewhere, that copied content must be correctly referenced. As a minimum, the source webpage or PDF etc. should be linked (references for books / articles should include title, author(s), publisher, edition, page numbers etc.). In order to help you, I found (what I believe to be) the source webpage link in this case and added it for you. For the future, please remember it's your responsibility to do that :) Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, this is my mistake, I will pay attention to it later. Thank you for your reminder.

Comment: @Iceeman Are you looking for the function, \$f\left(\right)\$, in \$V_{_\text{OUT}}=f\left(R_{_\text{LDR}}, R_1, R_2, VR_1, VR_2, V_{_\text{SUPPLY}}\right)\$, where \$V_{_\text{OUT}}\$ is the LM324 opamp output pin? (I'm not sure but it seems like it.)

Comment: @periblepsis Your understanding is very accurate, I would like to know their functional relationship.

Comment: @Iceeman That's a bit of an ask. Also, there is a ***lot*** of positive feedback and a fair bit of non-linear devices in the circuit. The upshot is that for a closed solution you would either be looking at an extremely complex expression involving some nasty-looking product-log functions or else only an approximation. For the most part, the output should be as "near the rails" as possible for the LM324. (Even what that means depends upon variations between devices as well as within the family.) For a short range of LDR resistance, there will be a very rapid transition curve (we hope.)

Answer (score 2):

The resistance of an [LDR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photoresistor) responds to light as follows

- dark - very high resistance, often > 10 Mohms
- very bright - low resistance, often < 1 kohm
- intermediate levels - a monotonic variation of resistance with light

As R1 and R2 set the threshold of the 'opamp used as a comparator' at half rail, you can expect it to switch when the resistance of the LDR equals the resistance of VR<sub>1</sub>. Different types of LDR will have different resistance/light_level curves, the datasheet will usually give a graph or a few points on the curve that you can design to.

The VR<sub>2</sub> control is labelled [Hysteresis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hysteresis). This alters the threshold voltage at the comparator, with positive feedback, to tend to hold the present value. Once on, the light level will have to drop lower to turn it off, and vice versa. This prevents 'chattering' from the comparator when the light level fluctuates slightly around the threshold.

As the amplifier is being used as a comparator, the output will always be 'high' or 'low'. This is a 'single supply' amplifier where the output can get quite close to the GND rail, but only within a volt or two of VCC, so outputs of approximately 10 V and 0 V.

When the light is bright, the -ve input of the amplifier is pulled up, so the output will be around 0 V. When the LDR is in the dark, the amplifier output will be around 10 V.

When the light is at an intermediate level, the hysteresis setting means that there will be two thresholds at which the output will switch between high and low. When the light level is between these two thresholds, the output will stay high or low.

As VR2 is reduced, the distance between the thresholds will increase, as there is more positive feedback. Usually I would expect to see an additional fixed resistor in series with VR2 so that it cannot be reduced to zero.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Perhaps my statement misled you. I don't care about the effect of light on the resistance of LDR. You can understand this as follows: LDR as a variable resistor R affects the output voltage of the amplifier. I want to know the functional relationship between R and Vout.

Answer (score 2):

LDR, or Light Dependent Resistor, reduces its resistance with more light shining on it. Together with VR<sub>1</sub> it forms a voltage divider, and as more light hits the LDR, the higher the V<sub>2</sub> voltage becomes.

The VR<sub>1</sub> sets the level of light or darkness at which the output relay is switched on.

The VR<sub>2</sub> sets the small amount of the distance between the turn on and turn of voltages (hysteresis) so that the output doesn't oscillate (keeps switching on and off) around a narrowly defined turn on/off threshold voltage as the light amount approaches that level (and it changes slightly with turn on because the light switched on at dark increases the amount of light which turns the relay off, but as it turns off the amount of light decreases and turns the relay on, and this keeps going back and forth fast). 
In other words, the VR<sub>2</sub> defines a "window" or a range of input voltages which are ignored once the relay has been switched on or off.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I would prefer to get a functional relationship between the LDR value and the voltage output of the amplifier.

Comment: @Neil_UK You have added more than I originally wrote, but it is something I know and would have said had I been questioned more. Thank you, I feel bad for having that much contribution to my answer. One question though: It seems that there should be a resistor between the (+) input of the op-amp and the R1/R2 voltage divider, and the ratio between it and the feedback resistor VR2 would set the ratio of hysteresis to the V1 voltage. Could the schematic be wrong and have that resistor omitted?

Comment: @Neil_UK Never mind, I have found the answer - VR2 forms a voltage divider with either R1 or R2, depending on the op-amp's output state.

Comment: @Neil_UK Who is "Iceeman" and why do you think I am him?

Comment: @EdinFifić Iceemna is the OP, and I thought you were him as I was totally confused, and put the additional info that I intended to put into my answer, into your answer. I've now reverted that edit. Apologies for any confusion caused.

Comment: @Neil_UK  I WAS confused.  :D

Answer (score 0):

The mathematical relationship between *illuminance* *Iv* (expressed in lux [lx]) and resistance for a photoresistor has the following form:

$$
R = K \cdot I_v^{-\gamma}
$$

Where K and γ are positive constants.

Datasheets don't specify K usually, but sometimes specify γ.
Anyway those two constants can be deduced from the datasheet if it provides at least two values of resistance with the corresponding illuminance.

Often the datasheet specifies two resistance values, R10 and R100, which are the resistance values corresponding to 10lx and 100lx, respectively.

From those values you can deduce γ using the properties of logarithms. In fact you have:

$$
R_{100} = K \cdot (100\,\text{lx})^{-\gamma}
$$
$$
R_{10} = K \cdot (10\,\text{lx})^{-\gamma}
$$

Dividing those two equations and taking the decimal logarithm you have:

$$
\log_{10} \frac{R_{10}}{R_{100}} 
   = \log_{10} 
       \left(
          \frac {10\,\text{lx}} {100 \, \text{lx}}
       \right)^{-\gamma}
   = \gamma \cdot \log_{10} 
       \left(
          \frac {1} {10}
       \right)^{-1}
   = \gamma \cdot \log_{10}(10)
   = \gamma
$$

Hence:

$$
 \gamma = \log_{10} \frac{R_{10}}{R_{100}} 
$$

Once you know γ it's easy to compute K from the general equation and a value of resistance, for example R10:

$$
  K = \frac{R_{10}}{(10\,\text{lx})^{-\gamma}}
$$

The equations I posted can be deduced by analysing [this document](https://arduino.benarent.co.uk/datasheet/BRO_PhotoconductiveCellsAndAnalogOptoiso.pdf) by Perkin-Elmer, a photoresistor manufacturer (see page 6 in particular).

Another relevant document is [this](https://www.tme.eu/Document/0b7aec6d26675b47f9e54d893cd4521b/PGM5506.pdf).

To use a reverse relationship to determine Iv from R you can see [this other document](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/projects/design-a-luxmeter-using-a-light-dependent-resistor/).

The gist of the math is that reversing the general equation above will give you an equation with the same structure. In fact, raising both sides to (-1/γ) you get:

$$
R^{- \frac 1 \gamma} = K^{- \frac 1 \gamma} \cdot I_v
$$

Hence:

$$
I_v 
 = K^{- \frac 1 \gamma} \cdot R^{- \frac 1 \gamma}
 = C \cdot R^{-\alpha}
$$

Where

$$
C = K^{- \frac 1 \gamma} > 0
$$
$$
\alpha = \frac 1 \gamma > 0
$$